# Keeping Record of changes (who ticked the checkbox, what time, etc.) in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I created a checklist in Excel using checkboxes.

I want to keep a record of changes in a separate sheet in the same workbook.

e.g. Who ticked checkbox, what time, what checkbox, etc.

Comment: You need VBA macro.

Comment: Hi Harun, I know it requires VBA macro. Point is how to write VBA script.

Comment: You didn't tag `VBA`. So, I assume you want via formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with following code.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
Dim sh As Worksheet

    Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    sh.Range("A1") = Environ("USERNAME") & " clicked CheckBbox1 on " & _
                     Format(Now(), "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
    Set sh = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Harun, thanks for your help. However the code did not work. I would be grateful if you please lay down steps also.

Comment: I used the following code. it record logs in second sheet but it does not log "tick" in box and it also does not show date and time Dim PreviousValue

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Value <> PreviousValue Then
        Sheets("log").Cells(65000, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = _
            Application.UserName & " changed cell " & Target.Address _
            & " from " & PreviousValue & " to " & Target.Value
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    PreviousValue = Target.Value
End Sub

Comment: Add codes to your original post and explain what error you faced.